# End name from Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

How can I get the end property name from a navigation property?

In my model I have a relation one to many as following:

[image]

So, when I have my `Team.Players` navigation property, I would like to know that, at the other end of its association I have a property call `Team`.

So, for that, first I get my `Team` type and then I get its Navigation Properties.

```
EntityType myType = irrelevant.GetTypeFromContext('Team');
var TeamNavigationProperties = myType.NavigationProperties;
```

Now I have a [Navigation Property](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=NavigationProperty&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4) from where I take the [toEndMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.navigationproperty.toendmember(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a [relationship end member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.relationshipendmember(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
NavigationProperty PlayersNavigationProperty = TeamNavigationProperties[0]; //Simplified code
String endMemberName = PlayersNavigationProperty.toEndMember.Name;  //Which resolves to "Team_Players_Target"
```

Is it possible, from `Team.Players`, resolve the end of the navigation with something like `Player.Team`?